Child of constraint affecting bone even with zero influence
https://imgur.com/a/CxAb7hf
I'm having trouble with the child of constraint. I'm using the Snow Rig and added a cue stick prop to the rig with a single bone. There is an armature constraint on the Cue bone, so it can follow the IK Hand.
I keyframed the armature constraint when I want the cue to be influence by the hand. For one shot, I would like the hand to follow the cue. I added a child of constraint targeting the bone.
The influence changes from 0 to 1 over a single frame. The hand follows the cue fine for the frames I want it to. The issue is even when the child constraint influence is 0, it affects all the frames before the shot. The hand behaves erratically.
The link shows part of the scene where the child of constraint should not be affecting the hand. Why is the hand still being influenced?
